# AngularJS Promise called from modal causes error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm currently trying to create some kind of modal dialog in AngularJS to Login a User. Therefore I created a small example using the template on the official [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) page. To authentication the user, the credentials are sent to an REST-service. For sake of simplicity I used a dummy to simulate an http call. The received data should be passed back to the controller which called the modal dialog but somehow my prmisehandling doesn´t work and I recieve an error that the following code is wrong:

```
testLoginService.loginUser(user.name, user.pass)
    .then(function (sessionId){
        user.session = sessionId;  
    });
```

Here is the error that occurs in the console:

```
Error: testLoginService.loginUser(...) is undefined
$scope.ok@http://localhost:8080/LoginModal/example.js:32:2
Parser.prototype.functionCall/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:10567:15
ngEventDirectives[directiveName]</<.compile/</</<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:18627:17
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:12412:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:12510:18
ngEventDirectives[directiveName]</<.compile/</<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:18626:15
createEventHandler/eventHandler/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:2780:7
forEach@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:330:11
createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:2779:5
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/z3xkGVpzapKMikIfq6ir?p=preview) is my code on plunkr. What causes the error in my code and how to fix it? At the end I want to work with data received from the loginService and display the sessionID or other userspecific data on the user interface.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following,

use a callback function

```
testLoginService.loginUser(user.name, user.pass,function (data){
        user.session = data.id;  
    });
```

the ajax request

```
    this.loginUser = function(user, password,callback)
{

    var wsUrl = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

    var soapRequest = {
                    title: user,
                    body: password,
                    userId: 1
    }

    var config = {
                headers : {

                }
            }

    $http.post(wsUrl, soapRequest, config)
    .success(callback)
    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        alert(req.responseText + " " + status);
    })

    };
```

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ucibA2X7s40BdxhOQ0K2?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Change your service call like this.

```
this.loginUser = function(user, password) {
    var wsUrl = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    var soapRequest = {
        title: user,
        body: password,
        userId: 1
    };
    var httpConfig = {
        method: "POST",
        url: wsUrl,
        data: soapRequest
    };
    return $http(httpConfig);
};
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/pjv9dTWso2fSawIygfSZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You need to add return to $http.post inside your service and handle success or error events in the controller:-

```
 //service

this.loginUser = function(user, password)
    {

        var wsUrl = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

        var soapRequest = {
                        title: user,
                        body: password,
                        userId: 1
        }

        var config = {
                    headers : {

                    }
                }

        return $http.post(wsUrl, soapRequest, config)


        };

       //controller
    testLoginService.loginUser(user.name, user.pass)
    .success(function (response){
        user.session = response;  
    });
```

You were not returning any promise inside the loginUser method of the service

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not returning a promise. Try this :

```
this.loginUser = function(user, password)
{
    var q = $q.defer();
    var wsUrl = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

    var soapRequest = {
                    title: user,
                    body: password,
                    userId: 1
    }

    var config = {
                headers : {

                }
            }

    $http.post(wsUrl, soapRequest, config)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 

        q.resolve(data.id);
    })
    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        alert(req.responseText + " " + status);
        q.reject();
    });
    return q.promise;
    };
```